# Scattering cross section from sum of delta functions in 3D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, scattering, dirac-delta-distributions, scattering-cross-section

we had the following question in our exam:

[image]

I know basic scattering concepts like partial waves, born approximation etc. and the solution of common potentials like coulomb or hard spheres but have absolutely no idea about how to approach this problem so have nothing to show for my "attempts " at solving it. please help!

Answer (score 1):

The three-dimenional delta function does not give a well-defined scattering problem, so more information is needed to even make sense of the question. For exampe what is $\Lambda^2$?

Comment: I apologize for the bad resolution that is $\hbar^2$ not $\Lambda$

Comment: Ah I see, Nonetheless there is no such thing as a three-d delta function potential.  At best it is a code for a *pseudopotential*, meaning that one treats it in first-order Born approximation. Look up "scattering length" approximation for more info.